# Laravel querying array

Tags: php, sql, laravel-4

I am trying to create a eloquent query to get the user results of an array of user id's. Is there a clean way to accomplish this using elequent instead of chaining wheres like this:

```
$users = User::where('id', '=', '1')->orWhere('id','=','2')
```

My array of ids comes from an API call and can contain as many id's as the call passes.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `whereIn`. This lets you pass in an array of IDs.

```
$userIds = [1, 2];
$users = User::whereIn('id', $userIds)->get();
```

Comment: Amazing! so simple and clean.. Thank you!!